# Where does Eclipse hide the keystore?

Tags: android, publishing, keystore

I'm surprisingly frustrated by this, and I suspect the answer is simple.

I have compiled and signed my android app using the Export Wizard, as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#cert) in the section 'Compile and sign with Eclipse ADT'.

I would like to backup the keystore and have it handy for future app updates, but I can't figure out for the life of me where the keystore is saved. I of course can use Eclipse to go through the process, but if something happens to my computer I'll be pretty screwed.

Does anyone know where it is stored?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't hide it. One of the first steps of the export (where you create or use existing keystore) asks you where you want to save it. You might want to go through the export steps again to see which path it is currently defaulted to and then check there.

It is typically saved with the name `key` (no extension).

Comment: argh. I knew it would be simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

I just spent a lot of time on this very annoying problem. On Windows, if you do not specify a full path when you create the keystore, Eclipse will hide it in its own directory. So in my case it was C:\eclipse\mykeystore

Answer (score 3):

it is very easy to creat the KeyStore, just follow the steps in your java environment, for exemplemine is java EDT

in your workspace (at the left), you have your project under(Package Explorer, Navigator), click on Navigator right clik on the top of your name project and you will have a list of items, at the last ones choose click on Android Tools ==> it will show another list, this one will display exporte unsigned package, export signed package ... and so on.
choose signed package and follow the steps where the system will put your key store(it's you ho decide will it should be)
choose any location you went, and give a pwd for that

good luck
RachidM

Answer (score 2):

So, here is how it is,
When you first export the project you will see the name of the keystore is the same as .apk
Change this! make it projectname.keystore for example
It was bit misleading but when you save the apk then it will replace the keystore and you cant really find it again.
Then everytime you export the project select the .keystore file

Answer (score 1):

I too was not paying attention when creating the keystore.  I am using the Motodev-wrapped Eclipse installation.  The default location for the keystore there is $HOME\motodevstudio\tools.

Answer (score 0):

The Android plugin hides its keystores in either `%HOMEPATH%\.android` or `~/.android`