# The final program does not show the map. Why?

Tags: android, apk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google map can be displayed on emulator but not in Android Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231830/google-map-can-be-displayed-on-emulator-but-not-in-android-device)

I want to get .apk file for final version, but when i install the program on the phone, the program does not shows the map but when i run the program in eclipse, the program runs correctly. I think, maybe the program doesn't have map libray. What is the problem? What should i do?

Comment: Yes. I export file and i have apk file and other file that i dont know what!!

Comment: To downvoter, you should leave a comment to help him improve his question.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions given on this page https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey ? Your Map API key mush be generated using your signing certificate (the one you use to sign your APK).

Comment: @PariyaDaghoghi: you should try create new key when export apk file.

Comment: [Duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5231830/1050058)

Comment: @Yul: Do you mean, i should to create a new key after i export apk file?? How?

Comment: When you signed export application, it'll ask you create a new keystore or  use existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are deploying using the Google Maps Api key for debug, not for release.

You should read https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey.

Hope it helps, and if you need more helps let me know.

Steps to generate apiKey for release:
1. Build Keystore  - from eclipse > right click on project and then android tools > Export Signed Application Package
2. Open cmd and write

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin > keytool -v -list -alias <your alias> -keystore <path to keystore>
```

where < your alias > is one used when generating the keystore
< path to keystore > to path where you have placed the keystore
  This command can be different for you.

You will get the MD5 code needed for generating the api key.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I obtain apiKey and i write my apiKey to my prgram but finla version not shows map. Do may i fill fields with incorrect information?

Comment: @PariyaDaghoghi: Just read the freaking instructions on the given page. You might have 2 API keys: one related to your debug signing certificate, the other related to your "export" signing certificate.

Comment: Did you got apiKey for android debug.keystore and for jre?  I had the same problems when building the apk and forget to change apiKey from debug to release.  If you didn't do both, you will have to build a keystore from eclipse (right click on project and then android tools > Export Signed Application Package) and then execute in cmd something similar to this command : c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin > keytool -v -list -alias <your alias> -keystore <path to keystore>    where yourAlias is one used when exporting from eclipse

Comment: Thanks for help but i don't understand what do you mean about your alias!! how i find this?? what is between bin and keytool? Thanks

Comment: You should check [this](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/02/sign-your-android-applications-for.html) tutorial for creating keystore (with alias) in eclipse.   If you want, you can read [Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Comment: I lost directory of keysotre! what should i do??

Comment: @Pariya Daghoghi Search it in windows or create another one :)

Comment: When i write this in cmd, cmd has errors. If i write C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin  in front C:\Users\Fahimeh> . but cmd writes C:\Programs is not recognized as an internal or external command. WHy? WHat is the problem?

Comment: You need to navigate using commands to c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin  and there you will write your command.  To Navigate backward you will write cd.. and forward eg.: cd Program Files (x86)

Comment: Thank you. I write this and i'm sure directory address and alias is true but cmd write The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: keytool -v -list -alias pariya -keystore e:\name.keystore.  I tested this command right now on Windows 7 and works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks
I write this and cmd not write MD5! I put pictur cmd in below.
[image: cmd]

Comment: check if you typed correct. Before keytool -list you probably have an illegal option caused by a misspelling