# Keystore Eclipse ADT file location

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have developed and released an app on the Android Market.
I compiled the release, signed and zipaligned with Eclipse ADT export.
This process created a Keystore for me in the wizard. 
The steps i took are detailed in the [Android dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#ExportWizard).

I want to know, **Where does the newly created keystore reside**? I want to take it and reuse on another project but i am not sure where i can find it.

I thought it would be named something like **my-release-key.keystore** but i cant find it.
Sorry if this comes out as a dumb question but i am quite new to this and is a wearied thing to get stuck on.

Edit:
I used the Eclipse ADT Wizard and in there i entered the location as follows...

[image: Keystore Location]

I am developing on a Mac and a very new mac user. I just dont know where this file has been placed. It i not in the project folder or the "cd /" location.

Thanks

Comment: Did you sign it manually or via ADT's (Eclipse) "Export Signed Application Package" feature?

Comment: See this similar thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588487/where-does-eclipse-hide-the-keystore

Comment: Yes  did use the "Export Signed Application Package" feature. 

Thanks for the similar thread link, But my problem is a different.

Comment: the same problem to me! how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using eclipse wizard you can explicitly set keystore destination folder. But if you didn't do it (in your case), eclipse will save new key in your home directory.

[image: Eclipse Wizard]

Comment: Hi, Where does it go if you have it set from **/home/a4e6/my-release-key.keystore** to **my-release-key.keystore**

Comment: It would be in my home directory /home/a4e6/

Answer (score 7):

OK, I found out the Eclipse ADT on Mac OS X saves keystores by default in Eclipse.app/Contents/Mac OS :-(

Comment: if u use windows it would be here C:\tools\Android Development tools\eclipse

Comment: That was scary... What a retarded way to treat such an important file. Also note that by default file will not have extension.

Answer (score 1):

You should manually create it with `keytool`. This step described in [Obtain a suitable private key](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#cert) part of the guide.

Comment: Hi, There is a debug.keystore at that location. But this is not a newly created. I presume this is the key used for debug on a system. but a debug key cannot be used to sign for android market.

Comment: My apologies. I misunderstood your question, delete and then edit the answer.

Comment: 4e6 - Yes creating it manual with keytool is one way of creating a key, but i have already created it with the Eclipse ADT wizard. I need to find the key that was created by the wizard and not create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Basically in windows(Checked in Window 7) the release_kestore stores by default in **`C:\Users\xyz\release_keystore`**. Then we have to move it to our comfortable place.